# load another partial if value returned is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

### Issue

---

I have a email box where a user enters their email which to then I make a web service call to check the email exists inside my controller. I want to them move to a partial called *forgotpasswordcode.html* if the email exists.

### Code

---

Here is the page where the user enters their email:

```
<div id="forgotpasswordWrapper" ng-controller="forgotPasswordController">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <form name="forgotpasswordForm" autocomplete="off" class="text-center col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img src="images/logo.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required placeholder="Email" ng-model="email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <button type="submit" ng-click="forgotpasswordForm.$valid && ResetPassword()">
                    <span>Reset Password</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button then points to the controller here:

```
app.controller('forgotPasswordController', function ($scope, forgotPasswordService) {

    $scope.ResetPassword = function () {
        //REDIRECT TO PARTIAL forgotpasswordcode.html
    };
});
```

I do have a routing engine set up like below:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

.when('/', { templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', controller: 'loginController'})

.when('/forgotpassword', { templateUrl: 'partials/forgotpassword.html', controller: 'forgotPasswordController' })

.when('/forgotpasswordcode', { templateUrl: 'partials/forgotpasswordcode.html', controller: 'forgotPasswordCodeController' })

});
```

How can I load another partial from my controller?

Comment: You can use $location.path( "/forgotpasswordcode" );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service

```
$location.path('/forgotpasswordcode')
```